# Spring Security @RolesAllowed Works but @Secured gives me AccessDeniedException in Spring 3.2 with Spring Security 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am having an issue where my Controller method with @RolesAllowed works correctly but if I try to use @Secured I get an AccessDeniedException.  While I would prefer to use the @RolesAllowed Annotation it has been declared that for this project we should Use @Secured because the name is less confusing when mapped to our legacy access rights.

I have the annotation configured as follows:

```
<security:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

When I use `@RolesAllowed("COMPANY_SEE_REPORTS")` which my user has, it works correctly.  When I use `@Secured("COMPANY_SEE_REPORTS")` I get an AccessDeniedException.  Just to make sure @RolesAllowed was working correctly I changed the role to a role that didn't exist and at that point @RolesAllowed threw.  So my question is how can I get @Secured to work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a security role with a name that ends with `ROLE`

[From Spring Security Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/authz-arch.html):

> RoleVoter
>
> The most commonly used AccessDecisionVoter provided with Spring
>   Security is the simple RoleVoter, which treats configuration
>   attributes as simple role names and votes to grant access if the user
>   has been assigned that role.
>
> **It will vote if any ConfigAttribute begins with the prefix ROLE_.** It
>   will vote to grant access if there is a GrantedAuthority which returns
>   a String representation (via the getAuthority() method) exactly equal
>   to one or more ConfigAttributes starting with the prefix ROLE_. If
>   there is no exact match of any ConfigAttribute starting with ROLE_,
>   the RoleVoter will vote to deny access. If no ConfigAttribute begins
>   with ROLE_, the voter will abstain.

But you can modify the RoleVoter prefix [`RoleVoter#setRolePrefix(String rolePrefix)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.html#setRolePrefix%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: That isn't really an option for our system.  The meaning of Role doesn't quite apply here and in our system they would call this a Right (with a role being a collection or rights).  We have too fine of grained security model and we want to turn on individual rights and not just at the role level.

Comment: I didn't try the work around because from the perspective of my Company they don't consider it a role they consider it a right (since we have very fine grained rights here).  We are just using the roles allowed option for now.  I may dig into the spring source later to see if they require Role to use @Secured.